# Using $compile in services asking for scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

Can i use $compile in the services as it is throwing error scope doesn't exist.

```
services.factory('getRegistersrvs', function($http, $compile) {

 return {
     getRegisterpage: function() {
         return $http.get(baseUrl+'signup', {cache: true});
     },
     replaceTemp: function(response, $elem) {
         $elem.replaceWith($compile(response.data));
     }
 }
});
```

Here response.data is the html data got from the ajax http.get.

I need to use it inorder to get the ng click work for the dynamic elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$compile` service always needs a scope to compile the given content. It basically executes every angular expression & code in HTML in context with given scope.

So you need to provide some scope in order to make it work like `$rootScope`.

```
services.factory('getRegistersrvs', function($http, $rootScope, $compile) {

 return {
     getRegisterpage: function() {
         return $http.get(baseUrl+'signup', {cache: true});
     },
     replaceTemp: function(response, $elem) {
         $elem.replaceWith($compile(response.data)($rootScope));
     }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access element scope with `scope` method:

```
replaceTemp: function(response, $elem) {
    var scope = $elem.scope();
    $elem.replaceWith($compile(response.data)(scope));
}
```

This approach assumes that `$elem` is and instance of `angular.element`. If it's not (e.g. pure DOM element) you need to wrap it `angular.element($elem).scope()`.

One more approach is to create new scope with `$rootScope.$new()` or simply use `$rootScope` itself, but of course it makes sense to use the scope of the element being replaced.